# Why are my images not drawing on the JPanel?

Tags: java, image, swing, paintcomponent, imageicon

I'm trying to make a hex board with hex images (720x835 GIF) on a scroll-able `JPanel`. I've overridden the `paintComponent` method to draw the tiles at different specific locations and used a timer to call repaint at each tick.

When  `repaint()` is called, `doDrawing` is called. When `doDrawing` is called, `choseTile` is called to draw the tiles with `drawImage`.

For some reason, the tiles are not being drawn and I'm left with an empty black panel. Why are my images not being drawn? Is it because the images are too large? The panel is too large?

```
public class MapPanel extends JPanel {

// Images for the tiles
Image tile1;
Image tile2;
//etc

// measurements for the tiles
int tileX = 720;
int tileY = 835;
int dimensionX = 14760;
int dimensionY = 14613;

//Use this to keep track of which tiles goes where on a 20x20 board
public int[][] hexer;

/**
 * Create the panel.
 */
public MapPanel(int[][] hexMap) {

    hexer = hexMap;
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(dimensionX, dimensionY));
    setBackground(Color.black);
    setFocusable(true);
    loadImages();

    Timer timer = new Timer(140, animatorTask);
    timer.start();
}

//getting the images for the tiles
private void loadImages() {
    // Setting the images for the tiles
    ImageIcon iid1 = new ImageIcon("/Images/tiles/tile1.gif");
    tile1 = iid1.getImage();
    ImageIcon iid2 = new ImageIcon("/Images/tiles/tile2.gif");
    tile2 = iid2.getImage();
    //etc
}

// Drawing tiles
private void choseTile(Graphics g, int x, int y, int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case 1:
        g.drawImage(tile1, x, y, this);
        break;
    case 2:
        g.drawImage(tile2, x, y, this);
        break;
    //etc

    }
}

// repainting stuff
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    doDrawing(g);
}

private void doDrawing(Graphics g) {
    int actualX;
    int actualY;

    //set the painting coordinates and image ID then call the method to draw
    for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 20; y++) {
            if ((y + 1) % 2 == 0) {
                actualX = x * tileX + 720;
            } else {
                actualX = x * tileX + 360;
            }
            if((x + 1) % 2 == 0){
                actualY = (y/2) * 1253 + 418;
            }else{
                actualY = (y+1)/2 * 1253 + 1044;
            }
            if(hexer[x][y] != 0)
            choseTile(g, actualX, actualY, hexer[x][y]);
        }
    }
}

private ActionListener animatorTask = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        repaint();
    }
    };
}
```

Edit: I've already checked to make sure the images aren't `null`.

Comment: If you print the (x,y) points (left upper corner of the image in the frame) you are generating they start at (360,1044) and end in (10800,13574), it seems values too big for a window. Are you sure you are computing them in the right way?

Comment: what about taking g.drawImage(...) into the paintComponent(Graphics g)?

Comment: 1) Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL. 2) Use `ImageIO` to load them, it provides good feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Following Andrew Thompson's suggestion; I used ImageIO. I was able to figure out that the way I was accessing the image files was faulty thanks to thrown errors by ImageIO.

Comment: *"I was able to figure out that the way I was accessing the image files was faulty thanks to thrown errors by ImageIO."*  `ImageIO` to the rescue again.  :)  Glad you got it sorted.